Mean variance optimisation as error-maximisation: why would negative correlation increase standard error of estimates?
"The unintuitive character of many optimized portfolios can be traced to the fact that MV optimizers are, in a fundamental sense, estimation error maximizers. Risk and return estimates are inevitably subject to estimation error. MV optimization significantly overweights (underweights) those securities that have large (small) estimated returns, negative (positive) correlations and small (large) variances. These securities are, of course, the ones most likely to have large estimation errors” (Michaud, 1989, page 33).
Struggling to interpret this. Say we estimate expected returns with sample mean, covariance matrix with sample covariances. Aren't the standard errors of these statistics highest for the assets with high population variances (which MVO underweights) and high absolute correlation (from my experience in equities these are generally positive)?


Hi: Michaud says stocks with larger returns, negative covariances and small variances will get over-weighted.

The larger returns makes sense, right. Ceteris Paribus, the optimizer will prefer the stock with the larger return.

The negative covariances contribute to making the overall risk smaller ( negative covariances tend to cancel out variance ) which is one of the goals of the MV framework. This is true because Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2 Cov(X,Y).

Small variances kind of help similarly to negative covariances. Ceteris Paribus, the optimizer will prefer the stock with the smaller variance.


Note that when the return of a stock $i$ is estimated, the sd of it is just $\sigma_{i}$ rather than $\frac{\sigma_{i}}{\sqrt{n}}$. Your formula is for when wants the sd of the average return of stock $i$.
I'm not familiar with your formula for SE(COV(X,Y)) but Michaud is referring to the size of the COV rather than the size of the SE of the COV.
I hope this helps.

I'm not big on using Latin but I saw that term "Ceteris Paribus" somewhere recently and liked it !!!!!!
